# Rmail with imap prompts no mail

Tags: email

I finished reading the completed chapter of [33.Rmail](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Rmail) but have no ideas about how to read an email.

~/RMAIL keeps empty,

Although, I could get some clues from "33.18 movemail program" and "33.19 Retrieving Mail from Remote Mailboxes"

```
imap://username[:password]@hostname:port’
/var/spool/mail/user == file:///var/spool/mail/
```

Where should I place the above configuration?

## Following JeanPierre' comments, I revised the configuration as:

```
;; Reading Mail
(setq rmail-preserve-inbox t)
(setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("imap://abst.proc.do:password@imap.qq.com:993"))
(setq rmail-movemail-program "movemail")
(setq rmail-movemail-search-path "/usr/bin/movemail")
```

M-x rmail but prompt:

```
movemail:  invalid server response:  movemail: MU_ERR_BADREPLY:mailbox `imap://abst.proc.do@imap.qq.com:993': cannot open: Invalid reply from the remote host
(No new mail has arrived)
0 new messages read
```

What's steps I missing?

Comment: Maybe just `(setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("imap://username[:password]@hostname:port"))` in your init file?

Comment: Try to run mailutils from a shell: `movemail -v  imap://etc` and possibly add more `-v` to get more information.

Comment: report error "movemail: wrong number of arguments" @JeanPierre

Comment: Oh yes my bad, you need to provide a destination file as second argument (see `man movemail`.